# Content-Type always text/html

Tags: http-headers

I want to allow users download files, so all works just FF attaches `html` because of

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

I set headers

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=pdf_'.date("d_m_Y_G_i").'.pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

but when I check headers it always `Content-Type: text/html`. Why that?

Comment: How did you check? Did you use a network sniffer? Or just look in the browsers information? it might be that the http server replaces the header if the content if the payload is not likely to be a pdf.

Comment: I check with FF plugin livehttpheader